# Regarding request.getParameter and JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In one JSP I have a JSTL `foreach` coded like this foreach var=i begin=1 end=rowsremaining.
And later in the code

```
   <td class=value align=left valign=top>
      <input name=${i}Last_Name value="<%=Last_Name%> type="text" />
    </td>
```

In the JSP that is called I have another forEach var="i" begin="1" end=rowsremaining
And in the loop...

```
      Last_Name = (String)request.getParameter("${i}Last_Name");
```

Question: Why are all of my variables Last Name, First Name, Address, etc. all getting set to null? I mean I can easily guess it is because the variable i is not evaluating into the record number I was hoping it would evaluate into. The preceeding html page source for the first jsp does show the input tag names to be equal to things like 1Last_Name     16Last_Name    etc.    So i evaluates properly in the first jsp but not the second.

Any ideas as to why? Thanks.

Comment: There may be more approved methods on dealing with this, but I solved my problem by (1) leaving double quotes off of the name attribute of the input tag and using the record number instead to reference each record. I.E. - <input name=<%recordnumber%>Last_Name  and (2) by referring to the posted arguments in the following manner Last_Name = (String)request.getParameter(Keyvalue + "Last_Name");

Answer (score 2):

The JSP EL is not evaluated inside Java code.

Scriptlets contain pure Java code.

Don't use scriptlets. Use

```
${param[i + 'Last_Name']}
```

instead of

```
(String)request.getParameter("${i}Last_Name")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use that in a jsp, as I keep receiving invalid syntax messages for the above.

Comment: Execute your JSP, and post the complete and exact error message you get, along with the code causing this error. Saying that you get "invalid syntax messages" without saying which message and which code doesn't help.

Comment: The jsp won't execute. I am using IBM Rational Developer tool to change the statement to what you were suggesting. I am obviously not understanding your exact suggestion. I have tried two things: Last_Name = ${param[i + 'Last_Name']}; And Last_Name = (String)request.getParameter(${param[i+ 'Last_Name']}); And for both variations I receive this popup error msg as I hover over the red line appearing under ]});    Syntax Error on tokens ( expected instead.

Comment: This is supposed to be used in the JSP directly. Not inside scriptlets. Scriptlets must be avoided completely. You don't need scriptlets, because the JSP EL and the JSTL do the job, and better than scriptlets. Inside scriptlets, all you can have is pure Java code. Not JSP EL. No expressions inside `${}`. It's written in my answer: *The JSP EL is not evaluated inside Java code. Scriptlets contain pure Java code. Don't use scriptlets.*

Comment: You don't want me to have expressions inside ${} but you are giving me param[i + 'Last_Name'] which to me is an expression. I realize that I had a bunch of java code including that statement in between <% %>. But I have removed that foreach JSTL for a While(rowsremaining > 0); but still I receive an error for your suggestion, but now it is a type mismatch cannot convert string to int  for    Last_Name = $(param[i+ 'Last_Name']);

Comment: You didn't catch me. My sentence meant: You can't have expression surrounded by ${} inside scriptlets. ${} doesn't mean anything for Java. It can only be used in the JSP directly or in JSP tag attributes. Not inside scriptlets. Of course you can have an EL expression inside ${}. That's the only thing you can have, BTW. Remove your scriptlet completely, and use `<input value="${param[i + 'Last_Name']}" name=...`

Comment: I'll do some reading :-) thanks.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el007.htm#BNAIM

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue with this line:

```
<input name=${i}Last_Name value="<%=Last_Name%> type="text" />
```

Shouldn't you quote your attribute values, like so?

```
<input name="${i}Last_Name" value="<%=Last_Name%>" type="text" />
```

Also, where is `Last_Name` declared and in which scope is it retrieved from?

Comment: Everything is double quoted, just not in the initial text that I wrote. Last_Name is declared in the jsp with String Last_Name = "";

Answer (score 0):

There may be more approved methods on dealing with this, but I solved my problem by (1) leaving double quotes off of the name attribute of the input tag and using the record number instead to reference each record. I.E. - Last_Name and (2) by referring to the posted arguments in the following manner Last_Name = (String)request.getParameter(Keyvalue + "Last_Name");